# Updating and Synchronizing multiple GPS Geopoints in android application

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, synchronization, location

I have an `Android` Project that helps a taxi driver to get the location of the passengers who request a taxi and place them on a map , the project have two parts(seperate Project connected via a webservice) ,the passenger part which reads the `GPS` coordinates of the passenger and update it every 30 second or each 200 meter and sends the update to a web service.
The second part is the driver part which reads the `GPS` of the driver sends it to the web service and then display only the usres who are only on the range on the map
I have a problem that i don't know how to get the `GPS` coordinates from the two parts to the webservice exactly at the same time to set only an accurate points on the map .

Comment: You now have enough points to upvote all helpfull answers

Answer (score 0):

you see example in system?    alway loop cursor GPS coordinates , Util fill require  ，Again next loop...   i'm  form china ,  my english  so bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two database tables to store locations sent by passengers and taxi drivers on your web server and store location(longitude and latitude) sent by passengers and taxi drivers. when taxi driver send their location to web server, you can query passengers table and find passengers who are near to location sent by taxi driver. then you can update map of taxi drivers to show passenger locations.

Comment: I do that but i want to get the updates from the driver and passengers exactly at the same time to fill the map with the most accurate place of the passenger each time the driver requests an update

Comment: what do you meant by `want to get the updates from the driver and passengers exactly at the same time` ? i'm not clear that.

Comment: I want to view only the passengers who are the nearest to the taxi and so I really need to get the update from the passenger only before some seconds from receiving the update from the driver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to syncronize both positions, there is a "trick":

Just add the timestamp to your location:

```
location = (timeUTC, latitude, longitude)
```

Use position with same or small time difference for display / syncronizing.

transfer time as 8 bytes long value representing UTC time.